# How to get the MAC address --hybrid app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have a hybrid apps and would like to track users clicks and need to identified unauthenticated users..

I am thinking about using the MAC id but it's seems to be deprecated in ios7..

However, I see that MobileFirst has an option to get a device id using
WL.Device.getID()

Please advise if this option would  work to get a unique ID or if there is a method to get the MAC id..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your MobileFirst version, but for this exact need you can use the Operational Analytics feature provided by IBM MobileFirst with its API, that allows you custom tracking... See here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_overview.html?lang=en

Comment: Thanks.I will look at the link.. My version of MobileFirst is 7.0.. We are using Kafka to get the Analytics and we need the device id  and IP address etc